# FlowLayoutPanel child controls overlaping

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

When there are more than 160 controls added to FlowLayoutPanel (with WarpContents=False, so all controls are in a single row), controls that are added after that index are stacked/overlapped over each other.

Removing one of the overlapped controls (when it's in view or close to it, quite strange) fixes the positioning/sorting issue.

---

Demonstration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfHIZ.jpg

Top FLP is WarpContents=False, bottom is True. Everything else is identical
Button1 adds 165 controls, Button2 removes 1 overlapped control in top FLP.

---

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour from occurring, so that I do not have to add (temporary) controls and remove them in order to fix positioning of other ones?

Comment: What are the sizes of the controls?

Comment: @LarsTech 200x200

Comment: 160 x 200 = 32000.  Add in some padding and your problem seems to be hitting the max value of an int16.  Your controls are too wide or you have too many.

Comment: @LarsTech Why does deleting one of the overlapped controls fix the issue then? Like I add 256 and 160+ get stacked at one point, then I just delete one of those and all get sorted properly then.

Comment: No idea why that works.  Feel free to dig into the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Layout/FlowLayout.cs) to find out.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm just a beginner, I don't know if I can do that. Even if In case I find something, how am I supposed to fix it?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you already know.  It's a hack, but add an extra control and then dispose it.  WinForms doesn't like too many controls, so be careful with that.